# Best practice when calling self object methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this

Let's say I have this code:

```
const MyObject = {
    a($els) {
        // What is the best practice here ?
        $els.each(function() {
            MyObject.b($(this));
        });
        // Or
        const self = this;
        $els.each(function() {
            self.b($(this));
        });
    },
    b($el) {
        $el.addClass('test');
    }
};
```

What is the "best practice" for calling another method in the object? Is there any downside calling the variable "MyObject"? Or is it better to use `this` and why?

Comment: What if you rename `MyObject` to something else in future? If you go with first approach, you'll have to make changes at two places.

Comment: Well `this` would make it more re-usable..

Comment: just use this.b(x) ?

Comment: Why `self = this`…?!

Comment: Looks a bit nonsensical: a(x) === b(x) here, so is there really a use case for this pattern?

Comment: @deceze  I assume for when the function is larger, when its easy to loose object scope...

Comment: I edited the question so the use case is more clear. Sometime `this` gets replaced in loops or other logic stuff, and I end up with `const self = this;` at the begining of every function, that's why I was asking the best practice.

Comment: That is something of a different problem: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/476)

Comment: @deceze that is/was a common work around for containing the scope of `this` before `=>` functions became widespread. Some polyfils will actually refactor `=>` into `var self = this;` for backwards compatibility (Babel does this for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with

```
this.method(params)
```

however if you have nested scopes, `this` could mean different things and get confusing really fast. To avoid it, use `var self = this` to create another variable pointing towards the right `this`.

Example:

```
const MyObject = {
    a(x) {
        var self = this;
        return x.map(function (a) 
        {
           // cannot use this here to access parent scope
           return self.b(a);
        })


    },
    b(y) {
      return y % 2;
    }
```

};

Comment: The more elegant solution for losing `this` would be `x.map(a => this.b(a))`…

Comment: I guess using `this` is indeed the best practice, but therefore I end up with `const self = this;` at the begning of most of my functions. This "code repetition" was the reason I asked ^^

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery. Without it the `this` problem can be avoided like this (pun intended;). If you really need jQuery, see the second part of the snippet for my take on it.

```js
const MyObject = {
    getAll: selector => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)),
    addClass:  (elements, className) => 
      elements.forEach(element => element.classList.add(className)),
};

MyObject.addClass(MyObject.getAll("[data-test]"), "test");
setTimeout(() => 
  MyObject.addClass(MyObject.getAll("[data-test2]"), "test2"), 1000);
  
// using jQuery I'd use
const MyObjectJQ = {
  setClass4Elements($els) {
    const setClass = this.setClass2Foo;
    $els.each( (i, elem) => setClass($(elem)) );
  },
  setClass2Foo($el) {
    $el.addClass('foo');
  }
};

setTimeout(() => 
  MyObjectJQ.setClass4Elements($("[data-test2]")), 2000);

// still I'd avoid  the use of [this]
const MyObjectJQNoThis = {
  setClass4Elements($els, className) {
    const setClass = $el => $el.addClass(className);
    $els.each( (i, elem) => setClass($(elem)) );
  }
};

setTimeout(() => 
  MyObjectJQNoThis.setClass4Elements($("[data-test]"), "bar"), 3000);
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}
.test2 {
  color: green;
}
.foo {
  color: orange;
}
.bar {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-test>div1</div>
<div data-test2>div2</div>
<div data-test>div3</div>
<div data-test2>div4</div>
```

Comment: I used jQuery in the example because I am actually writing a jQuery plugin. But there are many non-jQuery cases in which `this` value can change (callbacks, loops).

Answer (score -3):

I think you are confused about the difference between classes and objects. MyObject refers to the class of MyObject. The this keyword refers an the INSTANCE of the object. Im guessing you are wanting to accomplish the later,  si the this keywod is what you want to use.

Comment: `MyObject` is not a class/constructor, it's a plain object.